# how to print value if value are present in text file otherwise print nothing

Tags: php

i have a text file in text file string are change after one minute .i fetch the value from text file to my php page.i want display string with comma sepreated.but problem is that since text file change periodically so i want only display the value which are in text file if in text file no value then display nothing.but if one value present in text file display,if two or more value present display vaue with comma sepreated.

i tried but i could not found solution.

```
            $myFile="mydata.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
    $return = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
    fclose($fh);
    $return;
            $arraynum=explode(',',$return;);
 $server_msg=$msg .",".$arraynum[0].",".$arraynum[1].","
 .$arraynum[2].",".$arraynum[3].","
  .$arraynum[4].",".$arraynum[5].",".$arraynum[6];
```

string are

```
W444-REASON,A823-REASON,B982-REASON,C534-REASON,D222-REASON,E878-REASON,
F744-REASON,G666-REASON,H555-REASON,I888-REASON,J229-REASON,K999-REASON~PAPER NOT 
 COMPLETE
```

Comment: So you want to display the text file as it is?

Comment: Onimusha is right, if you use this logic you will output the content of the file as it is. And I recommend you to use a foreach loop to get values of the array

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in

```
$arraynum=explode(',',$return;);
```

It should be

```
$arraynum=explode(',',$return);
```